# Routing is not working as expected in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In a Flutter app I have the following code in main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      initialRoute: '/login',
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
    );
```

My Router.dart has the below code

```
class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    print('setting.name: ${settings.name}');
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeView());
      case '/login':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginView());
      case '/post':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PostView());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text('No Route for ${settings.name}'),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
    }
  }
}
```

and my home_view.dart has the below code

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('homeview');
    return Scaffold();
  }
```

I am printing the value of settings.name in router.dart. When I start the app I get the below output in debug console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:56463/QrArHr5Zg54=/ws
D/EGL_emulation(13000): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd5f1a540: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xd5f0f880)
I/flutter (13000): setting.name: /
I/flutter (13000): setting.name: /login
I/flutter (13000): homeview
```

Since initialRoute is set to '/login', I am not sure why am I getting

```
I/flutter (13000): setting.name: / and 
I/flutter (13000): homeview
```

I expected it to directly go to '/login' case and render LoginView. Can someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: The reason you are getting that behavior is that "*/*" is the base route. Meaning that no matter what it will always go through that route first to go to another one, "/login" for example.  But I don't suppose it stays on the base route, right? It just quickly loads it because it has to go through that route first to get to the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happening because you have use slash in initialRoute.For example, if the route `/stocks/HOOLI` was used as the [initialRoute], then the [Navigator] would push the following routes on startup: `/`, `/stocks`, `/stocks/HOOLI`. This is done for deep-linking. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp/initialRoute.html. Just remove the slash from initial route, it will directly push that route.